# is there a way to render a pdf file in a jpanel?

Tags: java, pdf, jpanel

actually i m using the library PDFRenderer, i can display the pdf in a JFrame but what i want is to store the content of the pdf in a jpanel to display it later.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you convert the pdf into an Image and draw the image with the paintComponent method?

Answer (score 2):

[ICEpdf](http://www.icepdf.org/) is an open source Java library for working with PDF files. It has classes which can be used to produce a [JPanel containing a PDF file](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/PDF/Using+the+PDF+Viewer+Component).

Answer (score 0):

There is also JPedal and Multivalent. A PDF is a complex set of draw commands so you either need to convert it to an image or parse and draw it when you want to display it.